# safely running user a provided pure function on a server

Tags: server

On my server I need to be able to run a program provided by a user however I do not trust users to provide code that is not malicious. The programs that are provided should only ever be [pure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function), that is, the result the output only depends on the inputs and running the program has no side effects. To achieve this, I would need to take as input some python code (or js code, or c or java or something else) and then run the code in such a way as to insure there are no side effects. For example, I don't want the user to be able to start running system calls and maybe get up to some mischief. To my knowledge, this is not possible in any main stream language (eg: python, C, js, java etc). Is there a language that does enforce the absence of side effects? I want to be able to run the user provided code and feel safe that nothing will be effected.

If there is no language that does this internally, is there a some kind of 'stripped down' language where one can specify a pure function and companion compiler that can then run the pure function on some input? Ideally I would like any such language to be Turing complete.

Comment: Lika a sandboxed virtual machine?

Comment: yes, this would work if perfect. From what I have read it seems though that you can't really trust VMs completely and sometimes a smart coder can escape from them

Comment: What server environment are you talking about?  How do you interact with the code?  And where does the output of these programs go?

Comment: Maybe this is what you are looking for: https://docs.openfaas.com/

Comment: I don't see how OpenFaaS could apply here. Could you explain further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a language that does enforce the absence of side effects?

no there is not. Because, languages are general-purpose and not only limited to small area of programming.

> I want to be able to run the user provided code and feel safe that
> nothing will be effected.

If you want to limit users to run codes that have not side effects, for example *sorting algorithms* and etc. Indeed, most programing languages have a basic lib like `stdio`, `system`, `sys` that are limited to basic operations and for extra operations like file read/write (side-effects), they need for example `File.io` to do these kinds of operations.

As a result, You need to check what libs are allowed and what libs are not and also when your **security-profiler** receives a pure code then it checks what libs are used and are they legal? if `false` rejects and if `true` runs.

These words are just *minimum valuable* solution, Indeed, for a perfect **security-profiler** you have to spend a lot of times for it.